# Rename specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would to like to rename two jobs of my datasets to "pastry". I created a dictionary with as a key the new name and as a list the previous categories

```
# dataframe for artificial dataframe
salary = [100, 200, 125, 400, 200]
job = ["pastry Commis ", "line cook", "pastry Commis", "pastry chef", "line cook"]
# New categories
cat_ac = {"pastry": ["pastry Commis", "pastry chef"]}

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"salary": salary, "job": job})

df_test.head()
```

And then

```
df_test.loc[df_test["job"].isin(cat_ac[list(cat_ac.keys())[0]]), "job"] = list(cat_ac.keys())[0]

df_test
```

Everything is working fine on this small dataset, but when I do the same experiment on my 40k rows of data, all the line corresponding to the following jobs "pastry Comis" and "pastry chef" just disapear. Or new category "pastry"

```
# We read the lines with the new category
df.loc[df["job"].isin(["pastry"]), "job"]
Out: Series([], Name: job, dtype: object)

# We read the lines with the previous categories
df.loc[df["job"].isin(cat_baking[list(cat_baking.keys())[0]]), "job"]
Out: Series([], Name: job, dtype: object)
```

Any idea of what could be the problem ?

Comment: Hi, it'd be great if you provide more details like an example of your data and how you are loading it into a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df_test.job.replace({i:k for i in v for k, v in cat_ac.items()})

0    pastry Commis 
1         line cook
2            pastry
3            pastry
4         line cook
```

***Note***: i think you have kept a space for the first record so it didnot replace which is intended since your working solution did the same, we can deal with them using `str.strip()` though

Comment: great solution. `replace` method needs `regex=True` argument though to capture job at index 0. +1'd

Comment: @ChrisA thanks, i was not sure if the OP wants that, if you refer to the OPs code after which says "Everything is working fine on this small dataset" i executed and found the replacement wasnt on the spaced string. So put it in a note. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I have the following error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-91bd4055ec2d> in <module>
----> 1 {i:k for i in v for k, v in cat_ac.items()}

NameError: name 'v' is not defined

Comment: @glouis the dictionary has a key and list of values right? as you have shown in the example? should be same for the solution to work

Answer (score 1):

Use your `dict` of replacements to replace using regex patterns:

```
for k, v in cat_ac.items():
    pat = '|'.join(v)
    df_test['job'] = df_test['job'].str.replace(pat, k, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df_test['job'] = np.where((df_test['job'].str.contains('pastry Commis')) | (df_test['job'].str.contains('pastry chef')), 'pastry', df_test['job'])
```